# How to get URL parameter to HTML field automatically angular 5

Tags: html, typescript, angular5

here i want to add this URL paramter automatically to the Admission Number field from Angular 5. please help me. how to do that?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to inject `ActivatedRoute` and `Params`. Then you can access the value via `Subscription`;

TS code

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {OnInit, Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  admission_no: string; 

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Note: Below 'queryParams' can be replaced with 'params' depending on your requirements
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.admission_no = params['admission_no'];
        console.log(admission_no);
      });
  }
}
```

And in your HTML do something like this via interpolation:

```
<input name="admission_no" [(ngModel)]="admission_no">
```

Answer (score 2):

Your component should look like this:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'foo',
template: '<input type="text" [value]="admissionNo">'
...
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
  admissionNo: string;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe(params => this.admissionNo = params.admission_no || '');
  }
}
```